# How to apply str.capitalize to the first word in the sentence?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a program that will convert a string into pig latin and I can't get it to capitalize the first word in the sentence. When I print the result, it's all lowercase. My code is below.

```
Sentence = ""
sentenc= str(input("Enter a string: ")).lower()
sentence = sentenc.split()
for word in sentence:
    part = word[1:] + word[0] 
    full = part + "ay"

    Sentence = Sentence + " " + full

final = Sentence.capitalize()
print(final)
```

Comment: You have three variables which are `sentenc`, `sentence` and `Sentence`? That is needlessly confusing. Please use better variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Your `final` string starts with a space, so there is no letter to capitalize.

Specifically, the first loop does `"" + " " + (part + "ay")`, then you continue adding words to that

One solution:

```
final = Sentence.lstrip().capitalize()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll be sure to change the variable names as well